# Conditions for deletion of an std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

Lets say I have the following:

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        int i;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> vector;
};

class FooBar
{
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<Bar> myBar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    FooBar foobar;

    foobar.myBar = std::make_shared<Bar>();

    foo.vector.push_back(foobar.myBar);

    foobar.myBar = nullptr;
}
```

Does both myBar and foo.vector.back() equal nullptr? Have they both been deleted? What would be the right way to do this? My endgoal is to be able to have a vector of pointers to objects, construct objects and put them into that vector from a different scope, then in the scope they were created in delete them and have them removed from the vector. My thought process is if I can somehow delete all instances of the pointer easily then I can just do a check each frame to remove the shared_ptr from the vector if it equals nullptr.

Comment: Never name your variables the same as standard classes, i.e. `vector`.

Comment: No, only `myBar` is null. `foo.vector.back()` still holds a reference to the shared object. That's why it's called `shared_ptr`. You can easily check this by adding constructors (including copy and move) and destructor for `Bar` and  print messages from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `push_back` you make a *copy* of what you insert, in this case the `shared_ptr`. So no, the object is not deleted because the copy of the `shared_ptr` still exists; as long as any `shared_ptr` still points to the object it is kept alive.

What you're looking for I think is a [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). If you pull one of those from the vector you need to convert it to a `shared_ptr` before you can use it, and if that conversion fails you know the object was deleted.

Comment: Make sure to emphasize that the **object** that is copied is the `shared_ptr` here, not the `Bar`. OP seems to be new and could easily misinterpret your answer otherwise. He could think that the `Bar` is copied onto the vector.

Comment: So I make a vector of weak_ptr, but construct the objects as shared_ptr, then setting the shared_ptr to something else like nullptr will make the weak_ptr expire. That sounds exactly like what I need, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `std::shared_ptr`, there are choices:

- Create an empty shared_ptr
- Share the claim of some other `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr`.
- Set up a new claim.

In the last two cases, the pointer can be copied as well or a (logically) dependent pointer can be passed.
Those choices can later be revisited.

Clean-up is only invoked when the last claimant releases its claim, (`weak_ptr` only counts for the management-object).

The important part is that a copy of a shared_ptr has its own claim on the shared object, and is otherwise completely independent from any other object sharing that claim.